How to sync global and local costmap in nav2?
In nav2, the global_costmap is used by the planner to compute path; the local_costmap is used by the controller to compute trajectories to follow the path.
Both can be filled in from an ObstacleLayer, that would detect obstacles, eventually inflated by an InflationLayer.
The planner would allow to compute path to avoid the reported obstacles on the global_costmap, but if obstacles are detected progressively, a path can end up crossing high costs cells, that we would actually prefer to avoid, and still be considered as valid as long as the cost of the cells is not LETHAL.
Depending on the re-computation rate of the path, a path can thus remain valid a certain time, while the controller tries to follow it.
On the other hand, a controller like the MPPI or DWB one, through their obstacle critics, can take higher costs cells into account, and give the trajectories crossing them a very bad score, to avoid them as much a possible during the path following.
My question is: is there a way to somehow synchronize the global_ and the local_costmap information, and to report the obstacles from the one to the other, without having to duplicate the processing of the same input data, like lidar or 3D cameras, in one ObstacleLayer instance instantiated by the planner and in an other one instantiated by the controller?
Locally at least, it could be interesting that both costmaps have the same information regarding the surrounding obstacles, right?

Typically speaking, we  don't want them to be the same. For example:

Resolution: may vary from global costmap (coarse, for larger spaces) and local costmap (fine, for trajectories in confined spaces).
Update rate: the planner may only run every few seconds or on a non-regular cadence depending on the application. No need to waste time on processing data that is unused.
Range: the effective useful range for the local costmap is no more than the costmap's size itself. But, the global costmap's range to consider things like lidar and radar can be far further and are more proportionate to the sensor's characteristics.
Layers: different local vs global costmaps may require different sensor, semantic, or other processing layers. Typically, I don't setup platforms that have identical local and global costmap configurations and I think that's pretty common.

Synchronizing is a bit of a different question - but first its good to agree on what you want to synchronize and why first (to know the challenges and needs attached to that information).
However, if you were to want to, a few options:

Each layer publishes its contents via a CostmapPublisher. You could create easily a new layer that listens to a layer and populates the costmap of the other based on it. You'd probably want to have the global costmap be the main costmap that publishes out that the local costmap listens to and populates based off of within its bounded rolling range. If you inverted it, then the global costmap would only ever have local information in it.
The Costmap2D server can be run standalone. There are a number of technical and latency-related-to-safety considerations why you might not want to do that, but you could have a single centralized costmap server that you use the suggestion above to populate each costmap from.
A PR could be introduced to have the costmap updated only on algorithm update (planner/controller called) or based on an external trigger which could be shared by both costmaps than thus in sync (some regular heartbeat).
Probably a couple of other ways I'm not immediately thinking of - these 3 are the most obvious and implementable

